# ¿Cómo exportar toda la BD con pgAdmin4?

Tags: pgadmin

recientemente instale **pgAdmin4**. Cambian algunas cosas con respecto a versiones anteriores, otras no están implementadas...

No encuentro la forma de volcar el contenido completo de la BD a SQL. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 3):

Para importar con pgadmin4 ten en cuenta que tienes la opción de importar toda la base de datos o una tabla concreta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## 1. IMPORTAR LA BBDD ENTERA

En **Tools > Backup**

Usando la utilidad pg_dump, pgAdmin proporciona una manera fácil de crear una copia de seguridad en un formato de texto plano o archivado. A continuación, puede usar una aplicación cliente (como psql o la Herramienta **restore**) para restaurar un archivo de copia de seguridad de texto sin formato o utilizar la utilidad pg_restore de Postgres para restaurar una copia de seguridad archivada. La utilidad pg_dump debe tener acceso de lectura a todos los objetos de base de datos de los que desea hacer una copia de seguridad.

## 2. IMPORTAR UNA TABLA CONCRETA

Utiliza la opción **Tools > Importar/Exportar** para copiar datos de una tabla a un archivo o alrevés.

La ventana de **Importar / Exportar** organiza la importación / exportación de datos a través de las pestañas Opciones y Columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A partir de ahí es ya ir configurando que tiempo de export quieres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo quiero exportar la BD completa, es decir todas las tablas de una vez.

Comment: disculpa, tu pregunta parecía que querías una tabla de la BBDD. Edito la respuesta para incluir toda la base de datos.